# QuickBlox inspect buffered messages

Tags: messaging, quickblox, buffered

Is there a way for a user who is currently logged off to know the difference between a message that is buffered while a user is logged off from when the user is logged on and receives the message.

If X sends Y 3 messages while Y is logged out of QBChat and then Y logged back on. Could Y be able to tell the difference between messages received while Y was logged off then messages recieved when both X & Y are logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When user Y will be online he receive 3 messages at once.
If you need implement chat history - please provide this (example for ios)
http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#1_to_1_Chat_history

Comment: That is not what I am asking.  I am saying, can I tell the difference between messages I receive while a user is offline, compared to when they receive messages when they are online.

Comment: You can compare received messages by text or date with existed.